# charles for capturing iPhone traffic doesn't work on iOS5

Tags: ios5, charles-proxy

We followed the instructions in the following page.

```
http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/
```

But it doesn't seem to work. A simple web address put in the Safari mobile afterwards would end up receiving error saying "Cannot open page - Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding". Was not able to find a solution for this problem, has anyone tried? Is there any special setting on Safari Mobile that could cause this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem as well, after updating from 4.3 to 5.1. The solution I found was to go into Proxy->Access Controls and then remove all the existing IPs in the list. When I next tried to connect from the device, I then got the permissions popup and all was well.